# Apache cannot run two virtualhosts with SSL at the same time

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a `httpd.conf` file with the following content.

```
<VirtualHost demo.mydomain.com:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo"
        ServerName "demo"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/demo.mydomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/demo.mydomain.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/demo.mydomain.com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost pay.mydomain.com:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pay"
        ServerName "pay"
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/pay.mydomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/pay.mydomain.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/pay.mydomain.com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

When I check the domains with an SSL checker, everything looks fine. But browser can run only the first one. The second one, `pay.mydomain.com` gives an SSL error and the browser says `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error.

If I remove the first one, `pay.mydomain.com` starts working. I have no idea what is going on and how can I solve this problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the names that are in your certificates. Your VHosts are configured to respond to the names `pay` and `demo`, without any further domain. A proper CA would in all likelihood not issue certificates for those names at all.

That you can put a name in the initial `<VirtualHost>` instead of an IP or `*` is a bit misleading, it's equivalent to putting the corresponding IP there, but it doesn't make httpd map requests to that name ot that VirtualHost block and [is discouraged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost).

So what I think you're seeing is that pay and demo have the same IP, you visit with the full domain name `pay.mydomain.com`, there is no matching `ServerName`, so the default (first) `VirtualHost` is selected. At that point, the connection fails because the certificate is only good for the name `demo.mydomain.com`. (I think httpd issues a warning on startup if you have certificates that do not match `ServerName`, but it's not a fatal error.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<VirtualHost demo.mydomain.com:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo"
        ServerName "demo"
...
<VirtualHost pay.mydomain.com:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pay"
        ServerName "pay"
...
```

with

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo"
        ServerName demo.mydomain.com
...
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/pay"
        ServerName pay.mydomain.com
...
```